# Lognormal approximation of the sum of successive values of a lognormal process

Tags: probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

I would like to use a lognormal process to approximate the successive values of another lognromal process.
Let $X_t$ be a lognormal process. I would like to approximate
$$ Y_t := \sum_{t=0}^T X_t $$
with a lognormal process.

Do you know any approximation method that would give good results? Should I rely to "standard" lognormal apoproximation?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: Is $T$ constant, or a random variable independent of the $X_i$ or a random variable depending on the $X_i$?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
$T$ is a fixed integer.

Comment: In that case, you might use the Central Limit Theorem and a normal approximation (not log-normal) if $T$ is large

Comment: My point is to use the process $Y$ in a specific fixed framework. It thus has to be a lognormal process.